# Unable to supply complex form values using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, perl-module, www-mechanize

I have an HTML form that I want to process with the [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize) module. It seems that I can't POST an input value that contains a dollar sign `$`. I get this run time error message:

```
Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at script.pl line 599
```

My script looks like this

```
my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1, ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 }, );
my $formfiller = WWW::Mechanize::FormFiller->new();

$agent->env_proxy();
$agent->get('https://site.com/form.php');
$agent->form_number(1) if $agent->forms and scalar @{$agent->forms};
$agent->form_number(1);

{
  local $^W;
  $agent->current_form->value('page_contentleft_0$form_D69D9E5239FC412ABB92A81D73F690AD$field_F40A1785D7B3490CBD5E72EDBE6B966D', 'John Doe');
}; #// First NAme
{
  local $^W;
  $agent->current_form->value('page_contentleft_0$form_D69D9E5239FC412ABB92A81D73F690AD$field_E3316C46A4404C73ACBAE107DF6206D2', 'Bridgeport');
}; #// City
{
  local $^W;
  $agent->current_form->value('page_contentleft_0$form_D69D9E5239FC412ABB92A81D73F690AD$field_E5747EB507E74DC1937557F9285CB57C', 'CT');
}; #// state
{
  local $^W;
  $agent->current_form->value('page_contentleft_0$form_D69D9E5239FC412ABB92A81D73F690AD$field_A612569BE44C4BA3AD0AB3FBF8FB0553', '06604');
}; #// Zipcode

$agent->submit(Submit);
```

As far as I can see the problem is from the parameters to the `value` method, for instance

```
page_contentleft_0$form_D69D9E5239FC412ABB92A81D73F690AD$field_A612569BE44C4BA3AD0AB3FBF8FB0553
```

How can I make Perl pass through the `$`, or to fix it in another way?

Comment: Setting `$^W` to `undef` is a little extreme. If you're getting warnings that you can legitimately ignore then you should write `no warnings 'category'`. See [What's wrong with `-w` and `$^W`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html#What%27s-wrong-with-*-w*-and-$^W)

Comment: As long as you use single quotation marks -- which you have done -- Perl is fine with any characters except another single quote `'` or a backslash  `\\`. You don't say which is line 599, but unless you have other calls to `value`, the problem is that `$agent->current_form` is undefined. Since you have just set the current form using `$agent->form_number(1)` the current HTML page must contain no forms.

Comment: line 599 is   $agent->current_form->value('page_contentleft_0$form_D69D9E5239FC412ABB92A81D73F690AD$field_F40A1785D7B3490CBD5E72EDBE6B966D', 'John Doe');
}; #// First NAme
{

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have?

```
$agent->submit(Submit);
```

Try this code instead:

```
           $agent->get('https://site.com/form.php');

           $agent->submit_form(
     with_fields => {
'page_contentleft_0$form_D69D9E5239FC412ABB92A81D73F690AD$field_F40A1785D7B3490CBD5E72EDBE6B966D' => 'John Doe', 
'page_contentleft_0$form_D69D9E5239FC412ABB92A81D73F690AD$field_E3316C46A4404C73ACBAE107DF6206D2' => 'Bridgeport',     
'page_contentleft_0$form_D69D9E5239FC412ABB92A81D73F690AD$field_E5747EB507E74DC1937557F9285CB57C' => 'CT',     
'page_contentleft_0$form_D69D9E5239FC412ABB92A81D73F690AD$field_A612569BE44C4BA3AD0AB3FBF8FB0553' => '06604'},
           button => "Submit",);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! however i still got an error message : syntax error at script.pl line 642, near "};"
syntax error at script.pl line 643, near ",)"
Execution of script.pl aborted due to compilation errors. ////////// please take a look into this : http://pastebin.com/WGQfJ5tU

Comment: You have a typo:  `''.$var4.''};` must be `$var4},`